# Single database won't load MySQL

Tags: mysql

When I turned off my MySQL server, and turned it back on, it wouldn't read my database anymore. Just a single database, everything else in mySQL was fine.

When I try looking at any of the tables it shows in phpmyadmin, it says:

```
orderofthebutterfly.tablename does not exist.. (all in lowercase.. even though i've set 
lower_case_table_names = 2 in the my.ini config.)
```

When I try to drop the db, i get this:

```
1010 - Error dropping database (can't rmdir '.\OrderOfTheButterfly', errno: 41)
```

I have verified that all the data is still there. There is a file in the MySQL directory with all the tables in it.

I have also deleted the folder and redid the database, and the same thing happened when I turned it on to work with the next day.

Comment: errno 41 is: "link number out of range". It seems a little bit tricky. First do a full filesystem check!

Comment: Are they InnoDB tables?

Comment: i've done a scan. nothing was found.. and my tables are MyISAM.

Comment: uninstalled and reinstalled mysql... db still corrupts when i shut it down and start it back up :C

Comment: Make sure the `my.cnf` file being used on boot is the one you expect. I have seen confusion where people create/use `/etc/my.cnf` but the `init.d` script is using `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or vice-versa.

Comment: yeah. it only fails when a specific database is loaded into it

Comment: i guess its just a bug. never happened in linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

litterally just reinstall. that's the only way. just redo that database.